# how to display two-dimensional array in rectangular output?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is not homework. I am a beginner (novice) java programmer, trying to read and complete the exercises at the end of ivor horton's beginning java book.

Write a program to create a rectangular array containing a multiplication table from 1 X 1 to 12 X 12. Output the table as 13 columns with the numeric values right aligned in columns. (The first line of output will be the column headings, the first column with no heading, then the numbers 1-12 for the remaining columns. The first item in each of the succeeding lines is the row heading which ranges from 1-12.

NOTE: I have only learned about Arrays & Strings, Loops & Logic, data types, variables, and calculations. I have not learned about classes and their methods and etc......so no fancy stuff please. THANKS!

```
public class Chapter4Exercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

     int[][] table = new int[12][12];


     for(int i=0; i <= table.length-1; i++)
     {
        for (int j=0; j <= table[0].length-1; j++)  
        {
        table[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
        if (table[i][j] < 10) 
         System.out.print("  " + table[i][j] + " ");        
        else
        if (table[i][j] > 10 && table[i][j] < 100)          
         System.out.print(" " + table[i][j] + " "); 
        else
         System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");       
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the numbers are less than 1000, try this:

As @Mr1158pm said:

```
public class Chapter4Exercise2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  int tableSize = 10;

  int[][] table = new int[tableSize][tableSize];

  for(int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
      table[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);

      if(table[i][j] < 10) //Where i*j < 10
        System.out.print("   "+(table[i][j])+" ");  
      else if(table[i][j] < 100) //Where i*j < 100
        System.out.print("  "+(table[i][j])+" ");
      else //Where i*j < 1000
        System.out.print(" "+(table[i][j])+" ");
    }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, i guess i should have explicity stated i need to do this using an Array, however, i assumed the statement above "Write a program to create a rectangular array" handled that for me. Anyways, yes, i need to do this with a two-dim array - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have to declare an array data structure to print out this table.
Just use two nested for loops and do calcs in the loops.
 Here is a working method that you can work on. Just need to fix column alignment, add space here and there.
FYI row<10?"  "+row:row is a form on inline if statement. If you haven't seen it before google it. It's quite useful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int row=0; row<13; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<13; col++)
        {
            if(row==0) //ffirst row
            {
                if(col==0)
                    System.out.print("   ");
                else
                    System.out.print(col<10?"   "+col:"  "+col);
            }
            else
            {
                if(col==0)
                    System.out.print(row<10?"  "+row:row);
                else
                    System.out.print(row*col<10?"   "+(row*col):(row*col<100? "  "+(row*col):" "+(row*col)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i am on the chapter "Arrays and Strings" , therefore, i should try to understand the use of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Back {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a1  =new Scanner(System.in);
    int row,col;
    String ch;
    System.out.println("Enter width of screen:");
    row = a1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter height of screen:");
    col = a1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter background character:");
    ch  =a1.next();
    String twoD[][] = new String[row][col];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            twoD[i][j] =  ch;

        }
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
    System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+" ");
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int width = 10;
int height = 10;

int[][] table = new int[width][height];

for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + table[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.